# Perform division by a variable using CPLEX

Tags: java, cplex

As far as I know, CPLEX allows to use the following methods:

```
addition method : sum()
multiplication method : prod()
subtraction method : diff()
```

I Am wondering if it is possible to perform a division by a variable, and if not, what are the possible workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an expression like

```
  constant1 = constant2 / var2
```

then you can rearrange it (like you did in school) to

```
  var2 * constant1 = constant2
```

Similarly if you have something like:

```
  var1 / var2 = constant
```

that can also be easily rearranged to

```
  var1 = var2 * constant
```

For more complicated cases, try looking up 'linear fractional programming'

Answer (score 1):

Can you manage with prod only? If not you can use a sum of all options with logical constraints.

Let me share an example in OPL to show you the way:

```
    dvar int x in 1..4;;
    dvar int y in 1..5;;

    dvar float z; //=x/y;
    maximize z;
    subject to
    {
      z==x*sum(i in 1..5) (i==y)*(1/i);
    }

    assert z==x/y;
```